# How can the equation $e^{-x^{2}}-2x^2e^{-x^{2}}=0$ be solved

Tags: calculus

How can the following equation be solved:

$e^{-x^{2}}-2x^2e^{-x^{2}}=0$

Answer (score 8):

Because for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ you have $e^{-x^2} \neq 0$, you can divide equation by $e^{-x^2}$, so:

$$1-2x^2=0$$

So $x=\pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Answer (score 4):

$$e^{-x^{2}}-2x^2e^{-x^{2}}=0\Leftrightarrow e^{-x^{2}}(1-2x^2)=0 \Leftrightarrow 1-2x^2=0 \Leftrightarrow x=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$